# i want multiple blog, themes and database

Tags: themes

i am running http://article-stack.com.
I want to create a separate blog say help.article-stack.com. Again, it should have 2 portion. One for discussion and another for information. I am planning to install wordpress in 2 more direcotries. Both will have separate database.
Tell me is you have some better solution

It will be helpful if you can suggest me some free theme for discussion. I am aware with twitter like theme p2. But it is not suitable for me. I want stackexchange type of site. So if someone helps others they must get their credit. It helps to motivate them and others.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 3.0 capabilities to run multiple site on single installation had been included in WordPress core. See [Create A Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) in documentation.

I have nothing to suggest on theme and I advise to split that part in separate question.